# Laravel doesn't authenticate users after migrating jwt from 5.4 to 1.0.x

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, jwt

Previously we used laravel 5.4 just fine with [jwt-auth 0.5.4](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth), we overrode [BaseMiddleware.php](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/blob/0.5.4/src/Middleware/BaseMiddleware.php) and we added our own logic to `app/Http/Middleware/TokenAuthentication.php` (the purpose was to separate authorization from authentication):

```
// The purpose of this middleware is to check the oauth token send in the autherization header.
// If the user exists, it is attached to the rest of the requests.
// This middleware does not check authorization, that is done in TokenAuthorization.php
// see https://scotch.io/tutorials/role-based-authentication-in-laravel-with-jwt
class TokenAuthentication extends BaseMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (! $token = $this->auth->setRequest($request)->getToken()) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        try {
            $token = $this->handleToken($token);
            $user = $this->auth->authenticate($token);
        } catch (TokenExpiredException $e) {
            return $next($request);
        } catch (JWTException $e) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        $this->events->fire('tymon.jwt.valid', $user);

        return $next($request);
    }

    private function handleToken($token)
    {
        $token = str_replace(['{', '}'], '', $token);
        $token = str_replace(' ', '', $token);

        return  $token;
    }
}
```

with our (relevant) middlewares listed in `app/Http/Kernel.php` like so:

```
class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [        

    \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,

    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    ..
    \App\Http\Middleware\TokenAuthentication::class,
    ..

    ];
}

/**
 * The application's route middleware.
 * @var array
 */
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth.jwt' => \App\Http\Middleware\TokenAuthorization::class,
];
```

My user.php looked like this:.

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;                                                              

class User extends Model implements     AuthenticatableContract,     AuthorizableContract      {
  use Authenticatable, CsvCustomCollection,
  SoftDeletes, Notifiable, EntrustUserTrait;
```

This all worked perfectly, but when we decided to switch to tymon 1.0.0-rc,

The problem with the new library is that this `Auth::Check()` keeps on failing in `app/Http/Middleware/TokenAuthorization.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class TokenAuthorization
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $roles = '', $permissions = '', $validateAll = false)
    {
        if (Auth::check() === false) { <--- always fails here
            return response()->error('Failed to authenticate because of bad credentials or an invalid authorization header :)', 401);
        }
        ..

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

One thing we had to change in our `app/Http/Middleware/TokenAuthentication.php` above is commenting this part out

```
$this->events->fire('tymon.jwt.valid', $user);
```

since the new `BaseMiddleware` of Tymon 1.0 has no concept of events per se.

here is the relevant part of our config/auth.php:

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],


'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
],
```

Now my userphp looks like so

```
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

 class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{
    use CsvCustomCollection,
    SoftDeletes, Notifiable, EntrustUserTrait;
```

What went wrong?

Comment: May i see the provider you are using in config/auth.php ?

Comment: @mohammad.kaab i updated the question